# What is that rapid changing number under Animation Node Tree?

Tags: interface, animation-nodes

I tried to check the doc and couldn't find it, the number under the animation node tree is changing very rapidly like its showing latency. Did I execute something I'm not aware of? I'm new to blender and it's freaking me out to be honest because I don't know what it is doing in the background.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number shows how long the last execution of your node tree took.

It changes all the time because by default **Auto Execution** is enabled. If you don't want that you can disable auto execution in the corresponding panel.

It is turned on by default because it makes it easier to get started.